# Row storage location in Resultset

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset, execute

What happens upon executing statement? does it retrieves all the rows into memory?Where the rows are stored in the `Resultset`, and how they are fetched into java program?

## Update

On calling `resultSet.next();` Does it goes to database fetch a singleRow come back at java side and display it? and `ResultSet` has `cursor` is it similar to database `cursor`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common misunderstanding is that the ResultSet must be some kind of container that holds all the rows from the query, so that people try to pass it around the application and are surprised that it becomes invalid when the database connection used to create it closes. The ResultSet is more like a database cursor, it's something you use to pull rows back from the database. The ResultSet has a fetch size that suggests to the driver how many rows it can get from the server at a time, so that it can retrieve the rows in chunks and buffer them for when they're needed.

Answer (score 1):

It is driver specific. E.g. Postgres JDBC loads all rows by default to memory, Oracle uses cursor on server side and fetches only part of rows.

Comment: so it means its specific to driver